# move blog posts from one wordpress to another

Tags: posts

I have a blog in the subdirectory.  Last year I installed a new blog in the root basically about the same thing.  I like to be able to transfer all my old posts from the blog in the sub directory to the root so I can close down the sub one

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your exact situation.

- If there's nothing in your new blog you can just point your new WP install at your old database (see questions on migrating)
- If there is content in your new WP instance and what you're wanting to do is merge content, then do an export from the old site, and an import into the new.

Do some searching here - there are a *ton* of questions about how to move domains / blogs / content.

Answer (score 2):

There are a tools for this built into the system - mainly System->Tools Import & Export. And then you want google to keep track of your new posts, while just changing the address- search engines will forget your old page slowly and take up the new one also slowly.
How to do it step by step -
http://www.wpcodelab.com/archives/how-to-move-a-post-from-one-blog-to-another

Answer (score 2):

It is very  easy my friends Go to :

step1: After login You can see tools-> Import and Export

step2: Which website content you can Export. Keep it safe

step3: Which website want to import choose import.

step4: select what you downloaded [click to][1] upload

Step5:Congratulations all posts are coped now